# How to deploy python in Azure logic apps?

Tags: python, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I am very interested in learning Azure cloud service in-depth and trying to do something awesome here, but not sure where to go or how to solve it. I tried my best to find any helpful resource online, but no luck. So I need some azure wizard to help me with this, please.

What I am trying to do is that I have a python script that I wrote on my local and want to deploy in Azure. My python script is designed to clean messy data that must be fed into the machine learning model. So, I created an email address where I receive the data from clients, and using azure logic apps, I will extract the files attached to that email and save it to azure blob storage. Then I want my python script to extract the data from azure blob storage and clean it then save it back to azure blob storage. Basically I want to automate the data cleaning steps in azure. Can anyone help me with which activity or service I should use to achieve this?

I really appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: you can look at azure durable functions where you can do the step by step orchestration or you can use the logic apps with azure functions combo to do the flow and processing.

Comment: @Aravind Thank you so much. Can you please share the link here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do 
1) Create a logic app to trigger on the email that you receive in your mail box. You can refine the way trigger is invoked meaning you have particular subject line, a particular folder etc
2) You can extract the data from files and feed to the storage account (You can also look at using CosmosDb)
3) Create an azure function which uses blob trigger or uses event gird trigger (To listen to Blob Creation event)
4) Write the logic to clean the data

Comment: this is awesome. Thanks for your help. Can you share the link to any helpful resources regards this area?

Comment: Can an Azure function be written in Python? Can you import Python modules?